# What does '@_' do in Perl?

Tags: perl, variables

I was glancing through some code I had written in my Perl class and I noticed this.

```
my ($string) = @_;
my @stringarray = split(//, $string);
```

I am wondering two things:
The first line where the variable is in parenthesis, this is something you do when declaring more than one variable and if I removed them it would still work right?

The second question would be what does the @_ do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `@_` variable is an array that contains all the parameters passed into a subroutine.

The parentheses around the `$string` variable are absolutely necessary.  They designate that you are assigning variables from an array.  Without them, the `@_` array is assigned to `$string` in a scalar context, which means that `$string` would be equal to the number of parameters passed into the subroutine.  For example:

```
sub foo {
  my $bar = @_;
  print $bar;
}

foo('bar');
```

The output here is 1--definitely not what you are expecting in this case.

Alternatively, you could assign the `$string` variable without using the `@_` array and using the `shift` function instead:

```
sub foo {
  my $bar = shift;
  print $bar;
}
```

Using one method over the other is quite a matter of taste.  I asked this very question [which you can check out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415297/is-there-a-difference-between-perls-shift-versus-assignment-from-for-subrouti) if you are interested.

Answer (score 12):

When you encounter a special (or punctuation) variable in Perl, check out [the perlvar documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). It lists them all, gives you an [English](http://perldoc.perl.org/English.html) equivalent, and tells you what it does.

Answer (score 10):

Perl has two different contexts, scalar context, and list context. An array `'@_`', if used in scalar context returns the size of the array.

So given these two examples, the first one gives you the size of the `@_`  array, and the other gives you the first element.

```
my  $string   = @_ ;
my ($string)  = @_ ;
```

---

Perl has three 'Default' variables `$_`, `@_`, and depending on who you ask `%_`. Many operations will use these variables, if you don't give them a variable to work on. The only exception is there is no operation that currently will by default use `%_`.

For example we have `push`, `pop`, `shift`, and `unshift`, that all will accept an array as the first parameter.
If you don't give them a parameter, they will use the 'default' variable instead. So '`shift;`' is the same as '`shift @_;`'

The way that subroutines were designed, you couldn't formally tell the compiler which values you wanted in which variables. Well it made sense to just use the 'default' array variable '`@_`' to hold the arguments.

So these three subroutines are (nearly) identical.

```
sub myjoin{
  my ( $stringl, $stringr ) = @_;
  return "$stringl$stringr";
}

sub myjoin{
  my $stringl = shift;
  my $stringr = shift;
  return "$stringl$stringr";
}

sub myjoin{
  my $stringl = shift @_;
  my $stringr = shift @_;
  return "$stringl$stringr";
}
```

I think the first one is slightly faster than the other two, because you aren't modifying the `@_` variable.

Comment: Good response.  I don't think %_ is ever used in Perl, however.  (I mean, it's never assumed and it's not a special variable of any other kind.  The user can use it, of course, but they wouldn't even save any keystrokes by typing, e.g., "keys" instead of "keys %_".)

Comment: I don't think I have ever come across any built in Perl feature that will use %_, by default, but it is still considered as one of the default variables. Or at least I think I remember reading that somewhere.

Comment: There isn't any word about %_ in perlvar. I haven't seen it at any place during my many years professional practice in perl.

Answer (score 6):

The variable `@_` is an array (hence the `@` prefix) that holds all of the parameters to the current function.