# Is there a difference between `shift` and `@_` in a subroutine?

Tags: perl

I always use `@_[0]` to get the first parameter and use `@_[1]` to get the second one. But when I search up code snippets online, I find many people like to use the `shift` keyword. I don't find the `shift` keyword being intuitive at all. Is there any functional differences between these two?

Comment: If you use `@_[0]` and `@_[1]`, you would get a warning saying it's better to use `$_[0]` and `$_[1]`.

Comment: Not using warnings is a horrible mistake. Never write code without both `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between Perl's shift versus assignment from @\_ for subroutine parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415297/is-there-a-difference-between-perls-shift-versus-assignment-from-for-subrout)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference between the two.
`shift` would change the `@_` 
(You could argue this would be an operation that would make shift slower)
`$_[0]` or `$_[1]` is just assignment and would not change `@_` at all.

The aesthetic way of writing this is  :

```
sub this_is_better {
    my ( $foo, $bar, $hey, $whoa, $doll, $bugs ) = @_;
}
```

Comment: So using `shift` makes it slower, and `@_[0]` is more preferred?

Comment: shift is not that much slower than simple assignment.  It really depends on what you want to do.  E.g., a common idiom is my $self = shift; my %args = @_; which removes the first element from @_ and dumps the remaining elements into a hash.

Comment: @user1032613: You specifically asked if there were any "functional differences"; you did not ask about "performance differences".  If you meant the latter rather than the former, please update your question.  (FWIW, I prefer the "aesthetic" way.  +1)

Comment: As for performance, the Perl interpreter recognizes a number of patterns and handles them very efficiently.  I would not be surprised if these were the same speed or if the "apparently slower" idiom were actually 10x faster.  Write a test and measure if you care.

Comment: Performance is tricky.  Perl 5.10.0 actually had a bug that made `shift` significantly faster than `my (...) = @_` (a list-assignment optimization accidentally got disabled).  It was fixed in 5.10.1.

Comment: With so many layers between your code and the machine, you can't guess at which operation is going to be faster.  Remember to [benchmark before making performance pronouncements](https://gist.github.com/3795945), `my($foo) = @_` is one of the slowest ways to get arguments.  `shift` and `$_[0]` are pretty much identical (`shift` is the fastest in 5.16 by a small margin) but its actually `my $foo` vs `my($foo)` which makes the difference.  SURPRISE!  **BUT** none of this matters, what you're doing in the subroutine is going to swamp any performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](http://p3rl.org/shift), `shift` without using an explicit array simply takes the next parameter from `@_` in the subroutine locally by removing arguments from the beginning and shifting the remaining elements to the front.

Comment: There is a functional difference ... shift modifies @_ while assignment does not.

Comment: @harleypig In a way it treats the array like a stack which is what I tried to explain toward the end.

Comment: Using "popping" is probably not a good idea in perl context, since `pop` actually removes an element from the *end* of the array.